# AngularJS. Pass stateParams variable to custom state data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state:

```
  .state('user', {
    url: '/user/:username',
    breadCrumb: {
      name: '{{pass here username from stateParams}}'
    }
  });
```

I need to pass `$stateParams.username` to `breadCrumb.name`. I tried to do next:

```
breadCrumb: function($stateParams){
  return $stateParams.username;
}
```

But it doesn't work. 
I suppose that I can do it in `controller` or in `resolve`, but I'm trying to find simple and elegant way. Could you guys help me?

Comment: I would be interested to know why you need to do this. My guess is you want the breadcrumb object inherited by child states. If so, I would say resolve is the way to go.

Comment: BreadCrumb object will used by breadcrumb directive and will be used in child states also.

Comment: So why can't you use scope variables?